# Google Maps - iOS: maintain map position after rotate device

Tags: objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ios6, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have 2 layouts (landscape and portrait) and each one with a UIWebView for show a map (Google Maps). Now I found the new SDK for iOS and want migrate, but I have yet a problem in both solutions:

the map open in the actual position (pos1) and I can move or make zoom (pos2). If I rotate the  device, with the new layout take again the pos1 and don't maintain the pos2.

How can I do for the map maintain the same position in both layouts?

Comment: Can you post some of your code, like what you do to set up the map view, and what you do when the device rotates?

Answer (score 2):

the easiest way is to use Autolayout to avoid having 2 different views. 
otherwise you can use the delegate method `mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView
    didChangeCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position` and save the position in a variable in your viewController